# HTTP Status 404 error in Eclipse using Tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat, servlets

When i tried to create a small demo in Eclipse with Tomcat (Tomcat 7.0.27, Eclipse Europa and Java 1.6.0_32 ) , i got this error when lauching the page :

```
HTTP Status 404 - /Demo/
type Status report
message /Demo/
description The requested resource (/Demo/) is not available.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.27
```

I recorded the screen, please have a look at this video (try playing in HD): http://www.screenr.com/L5d8

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Check Tomcat log files to have more info about the error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You created index page inside `WEB-INF` that is not public web area, your user can't access it directly,

Pull out the index page in webcontent (parallel to WEB-INF)